# Using Kerberos authentication for Server/Client application

Tags: c++, kerberos, single-sign-on

In c++ I am trying to build a portable server running on Linux and Windows and client running in Windows that will use MS Active Directory for authentication. After some research I decided that best way to go is use Kerberos. I decided to use MIT Kerberos v5 library due to BSD style licence.

But my problem is that I am completely unable to find good resource on working in Kerberos in C++. All examples that I found are just simple code snippets that fail to explain in enough details what input parameters to functions are and reference manuals (doxygen style) that briefly explains the function in question but does not provide enough information to understand the context where to use it.

In short, can you recommend good resource for C++ programmer that two weeks ago did not even know what Kerberos is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to start is the sample simple client and simple server in the MIT code distribution found here: https://github.com/krb5/krb5/tree/master/src/appl/sample

This shows you how to use GSSAPI to do mutual auth

Comment: The best examples I found are: "\MIT\Kerberos\src\athena\auth\krb5\src\appl\sample" and "\MIT\Kerberos\src\athena\auth\krb5\src\appl\simple".

Comment: Can you please give a link where I can download these samples?

Comment: they are in the mit source code distribution, which is now on github

Comment: Are there any examples that build on Windows OS?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you already have seen this, but the **[MIT Kerberos V5 API documentation](http://cryptnet.net/mirrors/docs/krb5api.html)** looks pretty exhaustive.

Comment: This API explains only Kerberos basics and provides decent description of API functions but IMHO lacks is examples on how to use these functions in code.